# How to use Redux Tool Kit 'mutations' with TypeScript: "Property 'push' does not exist on type"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

[image: WebStorm debug image]

I'm working with the [Redux Tool Kit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) in a TypeScript project.  One of the things the Tool Kit allows is using [mutations inside reducers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#writing-reducers), although one is not directly mutating the state -- when one is using their `createReducer` call:

```
const todosReducer = createReducer([], {
  ADD_TODO: (state, action) => {
    // "mutate" the array by calling push()
    state.push(action.payload)
  },
  TOGGLE_TODO: (state, action) => {
    const todo = state[action.payload.index]
    // "mutate" the object by overwriting a field
    todo.completed = !todo.completed
  },
  REMOVE_TODO: (state, action) => {
    // Can still return an immutably-updated value if we want to
    return state.filter((todo, i) => i !== action.payload.index)
  }
})
```

I've defined my state like this:

```
type InitialArticlesState = {
    articles: Articles[];
    currentArticle: Article | undefined;
    tags: TagList;
    currentTags: TagList;
    currentArticleNumber: number;
    totalArticlesNumber: number;
    currentSearchString: string;
    error: string;
};

const initialState: InitialArticlesState = {
    articles: [],
    currentArticle: undefined,
    tags: [],
    currentTags: [],
    currentArticleNumber: 0,
    totalArticlesNumber: 0,
    currentSearchString: '',
    error: ''
};
```

TypeScript now complains about `state.push` here:

```
[articlesReceived.type]: (state, action: PayloadAction<Articles[]>) => {
        state.push(action.payload);
    },
```

saying

[image]

What is the best way to solve this?  I'm a relative TS newbie, so it's not clear to me how to start.

### Edit

It would seem that when the app arrives at the reducer, state is a proxy for something else. So I'm not sure that types make sense in this context -- what is defined in the code is not what arrives at runtime...or is there a way to do it?

Comment: Any online demo?

Comment: @keikai -- Not yet, when I get a chance I'll try to get one up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a few different issues here.

First, your reducer function does not match the state type you've defined code-wise.  Your `initialState` value is an object, not an array.  But, your code is acting like `state` is an array by calling `state.push()`, which is why TypeScript is giving you the error telling you that's not possible.

Second, your `payload` is typed as an `Article[]`, but you're calling `.push()` somewhere.  Did you actually want to *assign* that array into the state and overwrite any existing articles?  If so, what you actually want is:

```js
state.articles = action.payload;
```

Third, by calling `createReducer` and passing in an object of reducers, you're going to have a harder time trying to type the state and action correctly.  Per our [Usage with TypeScript docs page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript), you should use [the "builder callback" form of `createReducer`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#building-type-safe-reducer-argument-objects) to get better typing behavior:

```
createReducer(initialState, builder => {
    builder.addCase(typedActionCreator, (state, action) => {
        // state and action are both correctly inferred here
    });

})
```

And finally, most of the time you shouldn't be calling `createReducer` by hand anyway.  We recommend using [`createSlice`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) for most of your logic, which will auto-generate the action creators for you.

Comment: Indeed, silly error on my part, which I saw before seeing your post.   I did indeed want to `push` since I'm adding to the array of articles.  I should filter as well -- perhaps I should make a copy, filter and then replace?  As to your point regarding the 'builder', I saw that, and will re-write it using that when I get the chance, but TS is happy for now.  Finally, there was some reason I wasn't using `createSlice` when I wrote the base a month or two ago, I can't remember why.  There was something that I wanted that it didn't provide.  I'll post if I re-discover what it was.

Comment: Rewrote it all to use `createSlice`.  Worked perfectly, although for a litle while one of my components seemed to be confused about `RootState`.